# PHP gettext: not all strings becomes translated

Tags: php, gettext

I have these two adjacent lines of code:

```
<td><?php echo __('Product', 'wpsc'); ?>:</td>
<td><?php echo __('Quantity', 'wpsc'); ?>:</td>
```

And these translations in the .po file

```
msgid "Product"   // Translates
msgstr "Produkt"

msgid "Quantity"  // does not translate
msgstr "Antall"
```

One string shows up translated on the webpage, the other not. And, yes I have tried to change the translation of the first one and confirmed that the translation changes accordingly, so I know the server reads the correct .mo file.
This is on an up to date Ubuntu server.
Any idea about what may be the problem?

Comment: Check for the line `#, fuzzy` above the Quantity definition. gettext won't translate fuzzy strings

Comment: That solved everything. Alternatively use the -f option to msgfmt

Answer (score 4):

As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139812/mark) mentioned in his comment, check for the line `#, fuzzy` above the Quantity definition. gettext won't translate fuzzy strings.

*([I'm adding this as an answer so it can get up voted, so that this question gets out of the unanswered queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/proposing-more-reasons-to-close-questions-question-will-never-be-answered-hav/60169#60169))*