# Gettext translations in php

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I'm using `gettext` to localize my web app. So far, I was able to get it working with a simple example, as follows :

```
<?php
    $dir = "../locale";
    $lang="fr_FR";
    $domain="messages";
    putenv("LANG=$lang");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
    bindtextdomain ($domain, $dir);
    textdomain ($domain);
    echo gettext("TEST 1") . "\n";
    echo __("Test 2"); // works if using gettext("Test 2");
?>
```

As you see, the last line tries using "__" instead of "gettext" which I read in several posts to be equivalent... So why is it not translating when using `echo __("Test 2");`?

Should I do a global replace in my source to replace all `__("` with `gettext("`?

Comment: There is no standard `__` function, `_` exists which is alias of `gettext`. Have you defined own function?

Comment: Nope, but `echo __("test");` works just fine and also, see e.g. this post...https://stackoverflow.com/q/2677229/2490877

Comment: I assume this is wordpress related ?https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: Nope this is standard `php`... I tried adding the `$domain` (i.e. `messages`) and still no success... So what I wrote above is, I guess, true - I need to globally replace `__` with either `_` or `gettext`?!